# How to iterate over columns of mysql table and return information in a spot?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, object

I have a MySQL table and the first column of the table is company names and the second column is a keyword associated with the company. Some companies have multiple keywords and the way I did it is if a company has more than one keyword they have multiple first and second columns. output.impwords is a list containing keywords that I have gathered from processing a sentence and getting the keyword. How do I iterate through the keywords from the table and then match that with the first column of the table which is the company name?

Here is a picture of the table [image]

My method so far

```
def match_tweet_for_website(self):
        output= WebOutput.WebOutput(input("Enter Tweet "))
        print(output.impWords)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        query= "SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM CompanyKeywords WHERE"
        for i in output.impWords:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```py
def match_tweet_for_website(self):
        output= WebOutput.WebOutput(input("Enter Tweet "))
        print(output.impWords)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)
        query= "SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM CompanyKeywords WHERE keyword = "
        results = []

        for i in output.impWords: 
          currentQuery = query + i
          mycursor.execute(currentQuery)
          result = self.cursor.fetchall()
          results.append(result)

        print(results)
```

Comment: I am getting the error mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'pipe' in 'where clause'

Comment: Did you use the exact same code I provided above? I'm trying to figure out where is mysql looking for a 'pipe' column in my code but I don't understand where could that be. Could you add the schema information of your table(s)?

Comment: I figured it out :) I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as correct if you think it helped you solving your problem